# Keep OSX sreensaver running after keypress

Tags: objective-c, macos, screensaver

In OSX, if you use many of the photo-based screensavers, you can use the right and left arrow keys to cycle through the photos *while* the screensaver is running.

I'm building a more customizable photo screensaver that allows the user more filtering options about which images are included, and I'd like to include the same arrow key functionality.

How can I intercept the key events so that they don't disrupt the screensaver?